# Need help identifying a vintage George Hine Production Co Rod

Tags: fishing, fishing-rods

My mother gave me an old rod that I think she just found and I need help identifying it. There are some pictures below. The whole group of pictures is  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bFVy.jpg).

Its only identifying marks is a sticker that seems to read

```
George Hine Production Co,

Santa Monica, California

The Harnell
```

It's a two piece rod, 9'2" when assembled. It seems to be a baitcasting rod since the eyelets are close to the body unlike the eyelets on spinning reels. The handle measures 23" from the the top where the handle meets the rod blank to the butt of the cork. The reel seat area is about 4" and screws down, maximum open area for a reel to slide in there is about 2-3/4"

What type of rod is this? I only own a single rod (i'm only a casual fisherman) which is the Fenwick HMG with a Daiwa BG2500.

I'm hoping this rod would be good for Salmon fishing on the American River and maybe surf fishing (or is it too short for surf?)?

What reel should I get to go with this? I am thinking something with the round baitcaster form factor to match the vintage feel.

Also it needs a new tip, can I just use any tip from a tip repair kit? I measured the rod blank to be 7/64" at the tip.

Lastly it seems there is at least one eye missing (the biggest one) and needs a new eyelet and winding. What can I use as a replacement eye and where do I learn to wind like this?

[image: Leaning on wall]
[image: Front face of label]
[image: Left side of label]
[image: Right side of label]
[image: Side view of wooden part]
[image: Area of rod with silver loop]